# Flattening column data with split then merging df with Pandas

Tags: pandas, data-cleaning

Using `names = df['Name and Location'].str.split(',', expand=True)`
I am able to split this dense data at delimiters like colons.

I'm stuck on how to recombine the data into a flatter record. I've tried:

```
pd.concat([df, names])
```

Records end at "complaint #", and begin at **date:** which is in another column.

```
Date: 1999/12/29
**Last_Name , First_Name**
City: City_Name
County: OUT_OF_STATE
Zip Code: 00000
License #: AA0000000
Complaint # AA00000000000

Date: 1999/03/01
**Company:** Company_Name,_INC
City: City_Name
County: County_Name
Zip Code: 00000
Company: Company_Name LIC AA0000
City: City_Name
County: County_Name
Zip Code: 00000
License: string_or_int
Complaint # AA00000000000

Date: 1999/05/04
**Last_Name**, First_Name
Company: Company_Name
City: City_Name
County: County_Name
Zip Code: 00000
License #: AA00000000000
Complaint # AA00000000000
```

Ideally, each "record" would ultimately be flat, like:

```
First Name Last Name Company City County Zip Code License Complaint Date  

Last_name_1 First_name_1 Company_Name_1 City_1 County_1 00001 AA000000 1999/12/29
```

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. I would read all of this as a text file, parse it and store every record as a dictionary in a list. Once this is done, it should be easy to recreate a clean dataframe.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome, @Erwan 
Would that method work for something that is multiple columns wide?

Comment: Well, doing the code yourself gives you full control over how the data should be parsed. You can split the lines according to a separator, and then interpret the content directly in whatever way makes sense.Personally I tend to go back to good old manual parsing in this kind of case, but there might be other options.

Comment: @Erwan there are 8,000 rows of this, and I am far too lazy of a coder to parse by hand. I'm in awe and deeply respectful that you would though. It certainly is called for sometimes.
I think I have found a solution in Pandas, though. Is there a best etiquette for answering one's own question?

Comment: Good that you found a solution :) [Writing your own answer is encouraged](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), there's no particular etiquette for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To split at a delimiter, and also create and combine a new column with the existing df, use:

```
df = pd.concat((df, df['Column_to_Split'].str.split('String_to_Go:', expand=True)), axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```

Any delimiter can be used, including an empty string. The key here is `expand = True` as it creates a new column, which was the goal.